# javascript getting a websocket error on onopen event

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket

I am getting an error about:

Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
Is there an event I can check to make sure the socket is fully connected before I can send a message.

My code is as follows:

```
        this.contextWS = new WebSocket(socketAddress);

        this.contextWS.onopen = () => {
            console.log('Websocket is open !!!');
            this.contextWS.send('payload');
        }
```

Am I making an obvious mistake here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49533457/1359764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the [MDN - WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) description:

> An event listener to be called when the WebSocket connection's
>   readyState changes to OPEN; this indicates that the connection is
>   ready to send and receive data. The event is a simple one with the
>   name "open".

I'd use *onerror* event handler to check if there are no errors on the way..

```
contextWS.onerror = function (event) {
   console.log(event.data);
};
```

... and *onclose* event handler to check the reason of unexpectedly closed connections:

```
contextWS.onclose = function(event) {
      if (event.code == 1000) {
        console.log('WebSocket closed normally');
      } else {
          console.log('WebSocket closed unexpectedly: ' + event.code);
      }
```

Here's the list of all possible result codes - [MDN CloseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent)

You can try to queue your messages and send them when the *readyState == 1*. Please see the answer from the similar question - [proxy function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23052382/3525449)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I read the MDN also. I am still not sure how to make sure the websocket is fully connected. I see the onopen event getting fired and I attempt to send a message and that is when I see the error. The only other events are see are onerror and onclose. Neither sees to be what I need

Comment: onopen event handler seems to be the right place to go. I've always been using WebSockets this way. Could you please update your example code and add the send() function?

Comment: I've updated the answer. There is a link to the similar question. The described approach seems to be reasonable. Anyway, onopen should work as the documentation say the readyState == OPEN when the event occurs. I've seen a few people saying that onopen is sometimes called twice - once for the readyState == 0 and once for the readyState == 1. Could you please print out the readyState inside your onopen handler? I'm curious if this behaviour really occurs.

Comment: I am seeing the websocket getting closed right away, so that is the core problem. Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.