# error "Failed to execute send on Websocket: Still in CONNECTING state" in Django Channels Production environment using SSL

Tags: nginx, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I'm currently deploying an application using `Django Channels` in Production environment.

The target application is based on the sample app from the official `django channel` documentation.
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html

I've confirmed that it works well in a production environment that does not use `SSL`, but it does not work well when changing the settings using `SSL`.

When executing the `chatSocket.send` function, the following error occurs in the developer tools console.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute send on Websocket: Still in CONNECTING state

So I modified the code with reference to the article below, but `chatSocket.readyState` does not change from 0.

[Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051416/uncaught-invalidstateerror-failed-to-execute-send-on-websocket-still-in-co)

How can I resolve this error?

---

Here are the codes:

room.html(javascript)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="chat-log" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea><br>
<input id="chat-message-input" type="text" size="100"><br>
<input id="chat-message-submit" type="button" value="Send">
{{ room_name|json_script:"room-name" }}
<script>
    const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

    const ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
    const daphne_port = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? ":8001/" : "/";
 
    const url = ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + daphne_port + 'ws/chat/' + roomName + '/';

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(url);

    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (data.message + '\n');
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function (e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
        }
    };

    function waitForConnection(callback, interval) {
        console.log('state:', chatSocket.readyState)
        if (chatSocket.readyState === 1) {
            callback();
        } else {
            const that = this;
            // optional: implement backoff for interval here
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.waitForConnection(callback, interval);
            }, interval);
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function (e) {
        const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
        const message = messageInputDom.value;

        waitForConnection(function () {
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': message
            }));
            }, 1000
        )
        messageInputDom.value = '';
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

daphne.service

```
[Unit]
Description=WebSocket Daphne Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/chat_test
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/chat_test/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/chat_test/venv/bin/daphne -e ssl:8001:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem:certKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullchain.pem chat_test.asgi:application
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sample.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.sample.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem;
    return 301 https://sample.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name sample.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem;


    location =/fabicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}

    location /static{
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static;
        }

    location /media{
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/media;
    }


    location /{
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/chat_test/chat_test.sock;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;

    }

}
```

---

**updated:**

I changed the nginx file, but still have the same error.

```
# location /ws/ {
#    proxy_http_version 1.1;
#    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
#    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
#    proxy_redirect off;
#    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
#
# }

↓    

location /ws/ {
    proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme       $scheme;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;

}
```

---

**updated:**

I changed `room.html` to Alexander's answer, but I still get the error.

The developer tools console show like this.

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://sample.com/ws/chat/room/' failed:

Then I check `/var/log/nginx/error.log` , get the following error:

> [error] 34188#34188: *10 upstream prematurely closed connection while
> reading response header from upstream, client: 123.456.789.0, server:
> sample.com, request: "GET /ws/chat/room/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://127.0.0.1:8001/ws/chat/room/", host: "sample.com"

Then I check  Daphne Service status with `sudo systemctl status daphne`, can see like below:

```
daphne.service - WebSocket Daphne Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/daphne.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-03-30 14:03:14 UTC; 6min ago
   Main PID: 34858 (python)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4671)
     Memory: 43.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/daphne.service
             └─34858 /home/ubuntu/chat_test/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/chat_test/venv/bin/daphne -e ssl:8001:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem:certKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullcha>

Mar 30 14:03:14 ip-123-456-789-0 systemd[1]: Started WebSocket Daphne Service.
Mar 30 14:03:15 ip-123-456-789-0 python[34858]: 2024-03-30 05:03:15,114 INFO     Starting server at ssl:8001:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem:certKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullchain>
Mar 30 14:03:15 ip-123-456-789-0 python[34858]: 2024-03-30 05:03:15,114 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
Mar 30 14:03:15 ip-123-456-789-0 python[34858]: 2024-03-30 05:03:15,115 INFO     Configuring endpoint ssl:8001:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem:certKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullcha>
Mar 30 14:03:15 ip-123-456-789-0 python[34858]: 2024-03-30 05:03:15,119 INFO     Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8001
```

Then I checkdaphne.service info with `ls -l`, can see like below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  455 Mar 23 20:41  daphne.service
```

Then I check ufw status with `sudo ufw status` like below:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
8001                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8001 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

---

ubuntu: 20.40

python: 3.8.0

django: 4.2

channels: 4.0.0

daphne: 4.1.0

nginx: 1.18.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell it has to do with your javascript in `room.html`, after some experimenting myself, I believe you can get rid of this `daphne_port` constant.

```js
const url = ws_scheme + '://' + window.location.host + '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/';
```

Only after removing it, I got everything to work locally and online with https/wss.

---

What was happening is, **only** when the server was running with https, `daphne_port` was being set to `:8001/` which would make the `url` equal to `https://example.com:8001/ws/chat/room/` which is (propably) not desired.

And since `window.location.host` includes the port number if running locally (`daphne_port` was empty), everything worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I fixed the code, but I still get errors.
I've updated the question with more details

Comment: @Tio Hmm the error in your update seems to indicate something wrong with the daphne webserver, are you sure its running ok and that nginx has permission to communicate with the sock at `/home/ubuntu/chat_test/chat_test.sock` ?

Comment: When I check status of  `daphne` I can check  the status is `active (running)` and I already did `$ sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'`

Comment: I managed to reproduce your error. In your daphne.service file, your start the service with your ssl credentials, is that required in your case? Because right now you are terminating the ssl connection when nginx routes it to the destination within your network. You can atleast see if that's the problem by changing this line `ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/chat_test/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/chat_test/venv/bin/daphne -p 8001 chat_test.asgi:application`. Then run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart daphne`